# Show that $\left(1+\frac{1}{1^3}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{2^3}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{3^3}\right)\cdots\left(1+\frac{1}{n^3}\right) < 3$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, induction, products, infinite-product

I have this problem which says that for any positive integer $n$, $n \neq 0$ the following inequality is true: $$\left(1+\frac{1}{1^3}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{2^3}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{3^3}\right)\cdots\left(1+\frac{1}{n^3}\right) < 3$$
This problem was given to me in a lecture about induction but any kind of solution would be nice.And also I'm in 10th grade :)

Comment: Can you show us your attempt? You will be more likely to get a response.

Comment: Maple gives us this term for your product: $${\frac {\cosh \left( 1/2\,\pi\,\sqrt {3} \right)  \left( n+1 \right) 
\Gamma \left( n+1/2+i/2\sqrt {3} \right) \Gamma \left( n+1/2-i/2\sqrt 
{3} \right) }{\pi\, \left( \Gamma \left( n+1 \right)  \right) ^{2}}}
$$

Comment: I suspect someone will prove the $n\to\infty$ limit is $\pi^{-1}\cosh\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Thanks for your comment but I forgot to mention that I'm in highschool, 10th grade so have no idea about that.

Comment: @J.G. You were right.

Comment: Does the OP have a beef with somebody?  It seems that somebody (most likely a single person) downvoted the OP and almost everybody who answered here at about the same time (i.e., about 9 hours before my comment here), even though all answers are sensible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving $\left(1+\dfrac{1}{1^3}\right)\left(1+\dfrac{1}{2^3}\right)\cdots\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n^3}\right)&lt;3$ for all positive integers $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1008934/proving-left1-dfrac113-right-left1-dfrac123-right-cdots-left1)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The cases $n=1$ and $n=2$ can be verified manually.  We assume that $n\geq 3$.  For an integer $k>2$, we have
$$1+\frac{1}{k^3}=\left(1+\frac1k\right)\left(1-\frac1k+\frac1{k^2}\right)=\left(1+\frac1k\right)\left(\frac{k-1}{k}\right)^2\left(1+\frac{1}{k-1}+\frac{1}{(k-1)^2}\right).$$
We note that
$$1+\frac{1}{k-1}+\frac1{(k-1)^2}=\frac{1-\frac{1}{(k-1)^3}}{1-\frac{1}{k-1}}<\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{k-1}}=\frac{k-1}{k-2}$$
for $k>2$.  That is,
$$\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1+\frac1{k^3}\right)\leq \left(1+\frac1{1^3}\right)\left(1+\frac1{2^3}\right)\prod_{k=3}^n\left(1+\frac1k\right)\left(\frac{k-1}{k}\right)^2\left(\frac{k-1}{k-2}\right).$$
The RHS can be telescoped nicely:
$$\prod_{k=3}^n\left(1+\frac1k\right)=\frac{n+1}{3},$$
$$\prod_{k=3}^n\left(\frac{k-1}{k}\right)=\frac{2}{n},$$
and
$$\prod_{k=3}^n\left(\frac{k-1}{k-2}\right)=n-1.$$
Thus,
$$\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1+\frac1{k^3}\right)\leq 2\left(\frac98\right)\left(\frac{n+1}{3}\right)\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)^2(n-1)=3\left(\frac{n^2-1}{n^2}\right)<3.$$

---

In fact, for a fixed positive integer $m\geq 3$ and for every $n\geq m$, we have
$$\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1+\frac1{k^3}\right)\leq t_m\left(\frac{n^2-1}{n^2}\right) <t_m,$$
where
$$t_m=\frac{m^2}{m^2-1}\ \prod_{k=1}^m\left(1+\frac{1}{k^3}\right).$$
If we pick $m=5$, we get $m=\frac{637}{256}<\frac{640}{256}=\frac52$.  So, we can prove a stronger inequality $$\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1+\frac1{k^3}\right)<\frac52.$$

---

By writing $1+\frac{1}{k^3}$ as $$\frac{(k+1)(k-u)(k-v)}{k^3}=\frac{k+1}{k}\left(\frac{\Gamma(k+1-u)}{\Gamma(k-u)}\right)\left(\frac{\Gamma(k+1-v)}{\Gamma(k-v)}\right)\left(\frac{\Gamma(k)}{\Gamma(k+1)}\right)^2,$$
where $u=\frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}2$ and $v=\bar{u}=1-u$, we have
$$\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1+\frac1{k^3}\right)=\frac{(n+1)\Gamma(n+1-u)\Gamma(n+1-v)}{\Gamma(1-u)\Gamma(1-v)\big(\Gamma(n+1)\big)^2}.$$
From the [reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula), and from the relation $u+v=1$, we have 
$$\Gamma(1-u)\Gamma(1-v)=\Gamma(1-u)\Gamma(u)=\left(\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi u)}\right).$$
Since
\begin{align}\sin(\pi u)&=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\pi i\right)\\&=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\cosh\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\pi\right)+i\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\sinh\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\pi\right)
\\&=\cosh\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\pi\right),\end{align}
we conclude that
$$\Gamma(1-u)\Gamma(1-v)=\frac{\pi}{\cosh\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\pi\right)}.$$
This leads to
\begin{align}\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1+\frac1{k^3}\right)&=\frac{\cosh\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\pi\right)}{\pi}\left(\frac{(n+1)\Gamma(n+1-u)\Gamma(n+1-v)}{\big(\Gamma(n+1)\big)^2}\right)
\\&=\frac{\cosh\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\pi\right)}{\pi}\left(\frac{\Gamma(n+1-u)\ (n+1)^u}{\Gamma(n+1)}\right)\left(\frac{\Gamma(n+1-v)\ (n+1)^v}{\Gamma(n+1)}\right).\end{align}
Since $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n+z)}{\Gamma(n)\ n^z}=1$$
for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$, we get
$$\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac1{k^3}\right)=\frac{\cosh\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\pi\right)}{\pi}\approx 2.42818979.$$

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful

Comment: But if you can tell me what was the thought process for factoring $1+\frac{1}{k^3}$ that way?

Comment: First I factorized $1+\frac1{k^3}=\left(1+\frac1k\right)\left(1-\frac1k+\frac1{k^2}\right)$.  I wanted to somehow rewrite $1-\frac1k+\frac1{k^2}$ as something of the form $1+a+a^2$ for $0<a<1$, so that I can use $$1+a+a^2<1+a+a^2+a^3+\ldots=\frac{1}{1-a}.$$  So I observed that $$1-\frac1k+\frac1{k^2}=\frac{k^2-k+1}{k^2}=\frac{(k-1)^2+(k-1)+1}{k^2}.$$  If I changed the denominator to be $(k-1)^2$, then I would get $$\frac{(k-1)^2+(k-1)+1}{(k-1)^2}=1+\frac{1}{k-1}+\frac{1}{(k-1)^2},$$ which is what I need.  That is why you have the "rescaling term" $\left(\frac{k-1}{k}\right)^2$.

Comment: I wish I could upvote once for the inequality and again for the exact calculation.

Answer (score 4):

Denote $p(n):=(1+\frac{1}{1^3})(1+\frac{1}{2^3})(1+\frac{1}{3^3})...(1+\frac{1}{n^3})$.

> **Claim:**
>   $$p(n)\leq3-\frac2{n^2},\,\forall n\geq2.$$

For $n=2$, we have $\frac94\leq3-\frac12$.

Then suppose $p(n)\leq3-\frac2{n^2}$ for some $n$. We see
$$\eqalign{
p(n+1)&=p(n)(1+\frac1{(n+1)^3})\cr
&\leq3-\frac{2}{n^2}+\frac3{(n+1)^3}-\frac{2}{n^2(n+1)^3}\cr
&=3+\frac{3n^2-2(n^3+3n^2+3n+1)-2}{n^2(n+1)^3}\cr
&=3-\frac{2n^3+3n^2+6n+4}{n^2(n+1)^3}\cr
&=3-\frac{2n^3+2n^2+(n^2+6n+4)}{n^2(n+1)^3}\cr
&\leq3-\frac{2n^2(n+1)}{n^2(n+1)^3}\cr
&\leq3-\frac2{(n+1)^2}}.$$

---

As pointed out by @saulspatz, one can prove that $p(n)\leq3-\frac1n,\forall n\geq1$ by the same method.

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot

Comment: +1 If I'm not mistaken, you can prove $p(n)\geq3-{1\over n}, n\geq1$ by the same method an a little simpler algebra.

Comment: @saulspatz I think you mean $p(n)\leq3-\frac1n$. Indeed this is a sharper result and easier to prove. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @awllower Yes, that was a typo, but it's too late to edit the comment.

Answer (score 3):

We have that

$$\prod_{k=1}^\infty \left(1+\frac{1}{k^3}\right)<3\iff \sum_{k=1}^\infty  \log\left(1+\frac{1}{k^3}\right)<\log 3$$

and since $\forall x>0\, \log(1+x)<x$

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty  \log\left(1+\frac{1}{k^3}\right)=\log 2+\sum_{k=2}^\infty  \log\left(1+\frac{1}{k^3}\right)<\log 2+\sum_{k=2}^\infty  \frac{1}{k^3}<\log 3$$

Answer (score 3):

Taking seriously the suggestions of Dr. Sonnhard Graubner and J.G., one can indeed prove that, for $x\in\mathbb{C}$ and $p\in\mathbb{N}_+$,
$$
\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1+\frac{x^p}{n^p}\right) =
\prod_{j=1}^p \frac{1}{\Gamma(1+\omega_p^j x)} ,
$$
where $\{-\omega_p^j\}_{j=1}^p$ are the $p$-th roots of $-1$.

In fact, using that $\sum_{j=1}^p \omega_p^j = 0$ and [this identity](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma/08/0001/) (see also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Weierstrass's_definition)), one has that
$$
\prod_{n=1}^N \left(1+\frac{x^p}{n^p}\right) =
\prod_{j=1}^p \prod_{n=1}^N \left(1+\frac{\omega_p^j x}{n}\right) =
\prod_{j=1}^p e^{-\omega_p^j x \gamma}
    \prod_{n=1}^N \left(1+\frac{\omega_p^j x}{n}\right) e^{-\frac{\omega_p^j x}{n}}
$$
converges, as $N\to\infty$, to
$$
\prod_{j=1}^p \frac{1}{\omega_p^j x \Gamma(\omega_p^j x)} =
\prod_{j=1}^p \frac{1}{\Gamma(1+\omega_p^j x)}.
$$

Specializing for $p=3$ and $x=1$ and using the formula for the absolute value [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties), we have
$$
\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1+\frac{1}{n^p}\right) =
\frac1{\Gamma(1+1)\Gamma(1-\frac12-\frac{\sqrt3 i}2)\Gamma(1-\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3 i}2)} = \frac1{|\Gamma(\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3 i}2)|} = \frac{\cosh\left(\frac{\sqrt3 }2\pi\right)}{\pi} .
$$

Comment: Very nice.  Indeed, if $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m$ and $y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_m$ are complex numbers which are not positive integers such that $x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_m=y_1+y_2+\ldots+y_m$.  Then, $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty\,\prod_{j=1}^m\,\left(\frac{n-x_j}{n-y_j}\right)=\prod_{j=1}^m\,\left(\frac{\Gamma\left(1-y_j\right)}{\Gamma\left(1-x_j\right)}\right)\,.$$

Comment: On the other hand, if $\displaystyle\text{Re}\left(\sum_{j=1}^m\,x_j-\sum_{j=1}^m\,y_j\right)>0$, then $\displaystyle\prod_{n=1}^\infty\,\prod_{j=1}^m\,\left(\frac{n-x_j}{n-y_j}\right)=0$, and  if $\displaystyle\text{Re}\left(\sum_{j=1}^m\,x_j-\sum_{j=1}^m\,y_j\right)<0$, then $\displaystyle\prod_{n=1}^\infty\,\prod_{j=1}^m\,\left(\frac{n-x_j}{n-y_j}\right)=\infty$.

Comment: If $\displaystyle\text{Re}\left(\sum_{j=1}^m\,x_j-\sum_{j=1}^m\,y_j\right)=0$, but $\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^m\,x_j-\sum_{j=1}^m\,y_j\neq 0$, then $\displaystyle\prod_{n=1}^\infty\,\prod_{j=1}^m\,\left(\frac{n-x_j}{n-y_j}\right)$ does not converge at all in $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$.

Comment: @Batominovski very interesting generalization!

Answer (score 1):

With $AM-GM$
\begin{align}
1.(1+\frac{1}{2^3})(1+\frac{1}{3^3})\cdots(1+\frac{1}{n^3}) 
&\leq\left(\dfrac1n(n+\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{3^3}+\frac{1}{4^3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^3})\right)^n \\
&\leq\left(\dfrac1n(n+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^3}-1)\right)^n \\
&\leq\left(\dfrac1n(n+\zeta(3)-1)\right)^n \\
&\leq\left(1+\dfrac{\zeta(3)-1}{n}\right)^n \\
&< e^{\zeta(3)-1}\\
&<\frac32
\end{align}
Thanks to [Winther](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/147873).

Comment: That doesn't work because $\zeta(3)>\ln 3> 1$.

Answer (score 1):

By **induction** we can prove the stronger

$$\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1+\frac{1}{k^3}\right)<3\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

indeed

**1. base cases**: by inspection the inequality is satisfied for for
    $n=1,2, 3$

**2. induction step**:

- assume true that (*Ind. Hyp.*): $\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1+\frac{1}{k^3}\right)<3\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)$
- we want to prove that: $\prod_{k=1}^{n+1}\left(1+\frac{1}{k^3}\right)<3\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)$

then we have

$$\prod_{k=1}^{n+1}\left(1+\frac{1}{k^3}\right)=\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1+\frac{1}{k^3}\right) \cdot \left(1+\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}\right)<$$
$$\stackrel{Ind. Hyp.}<3\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}\right)\stackrel{?}<3\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)$$

thus we need to show that

$$3\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}\right)\stackrel{?}<3\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)$$

which is true indeed

$$1+\frac{1}{{n+1}^3}-\frac1n-\frac{1}{n(n+1)^3}\stackrel{?}<1-\frac{1}{n+1}$$

$$n-(n+1)^3-1\stackrel{?}<-n(n+1)^2$$

$$n-n^3-3n^2-3n-1-1\stackrel{?}<-n^3-2n^2-n$$

$$n^2+n+2\stackrel{?}>0$$

Comment: Very helpful thanks

Comment: @LazarIonutRadu I just want to give an answer to your original question for a method by induction, it is interesting since how you can see we need to consider a stronger inequality to can proceed by induction. It is a typical case we can encounter with the method.

Answer (score 1):

**Claim:**

For all positive integers $n$, we have
$$\prod_{k=1}^n \left(1+\frac{1}{k^3}\right) < e$$
or equivalently
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{k^3}\right) < 1$$
**Proof:**

It suffices to show that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{k^3}\right) < 1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\tag{*}$$
holds for all positive integers $n$.

To prove $(*)$, proceed by induction on $n$.

By direct evaluation, $(*)$ holds for the base case $n=1$.

Suppose $(*)$ holds for some positive integer $n$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{k^3}\right)\\[4pt]
=\;&
\left(
\sum_{k=1}^n \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{k^3}\right)
\right)
+
\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}\right)
\\[4pt]
<\;&
\left( 1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)
+
\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}\right)
&&\text{[by the inductive hypothesis]}
\\[4pt]
<\;&
\left( 1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)
+
\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}
&&\text{[since $\ln(1+x) < x$, for all $x > 0$]}
\\[4pt]
=\;&\left(1-\frac{1}{(n+2)^2}\right)-\frac{n^2+n-1}{(n+1)^3(n+2)^2}
\\[4pt]
<\;&1-\frac{1}{(n+2)^2}
&&\text{[since $n^2+n-1 > 0$]}
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
which completes the induction, and thus proves the claim.

Answer (score 1):

**Less Than $\boldsymbol{3}$**

The inequality
$$
1+\frac1{n^3}\lt\frac{1+\frac1{2(n-1)^2}}{1+\frac1{2n^2}}\tag1
$$
can be verified by cross-multiplying and then multiplying both sides by $2n^5(n-1)^2$; that is,
$$
2n^7-4n^6+3n^5\underbrace{-3n^3+3n^2-2n+1}_\text{$-(3n^2+2)(n-1)-1\lt0$ for $n\ge1$}\lt2n^7-4n^6+3n^5\tag2
$$
Therefore, employing a telescoping product,
$$
\begin{align}
\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac1{n^3}\right)
&\lt2\prod_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1+\frac1{2(n-1)^2}}{1+\frac1{2n^2}}\\
&=2\cdot\frac32\\[9pt]
&=3\tag3
\end{align}
$$

---

**Actual Value**
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{k^3+1}{k^3}
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n+2)\,\Gamma\!\left(n+\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)\Gamma\!\left(n+\frac12-i\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)}{\Gamma(2)\,\Gamma\!\left(\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)\Gamma\!\left(\frac12-i\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)\Gamma(n+1)^3}\tag4\\
&=\frac1{\Gamma\!\left(\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)\Gamma\!\left(\frac12-i\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)}\\
&\times\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n+2)\,\Gamma\!\left(n+\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)\Gamma\!\left(n+\frac12-i\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)}{\Gamma(n+1)^3}\tag5\\
&=\frac{\sin\left(\frac\pi2+i\frac{\pi\sqrt3}2\right)}{\pi}\times1\tag6\\[6pt]
&=\frac{\cosh\left(\frac{\pi\sqrt3}2\right)}{\pi}\tag7
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(4)$: $\prod\limits_{k=1}^n(k+x)=\frac{\Gamma(n+1+x)}{\Gamma(1+x)}$ and $k^3+1=(k+1)\left(k-\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)\left(k-\frac12-i\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)$
$(5)$: pull out the constant factor using $\Gamma(2)=1$
$(6)$: apply [Euler's Reflection Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General) $\Gamma(x)\,\Gamma(1-x)=\frac\pi{\sin(\pi x)}$
$\phantom{(6)\text{:}}$ and [Gautschi's Inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/103028), which implies $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n+x)}{\Gamma(n)\,n^x}=1$
$(7)$: $\cos(ix)=\cosh(x)$