# Prove that $(1+ \frac{1}{1^3})(1+\frac{1}{2^3})...(1+\frac{1}{n^3})<3$

Tags: inequality, induction

I have tried to use induction, but after I assume that P(n) is true, I can't go further to prove that P(n+1) is true as well. I also have tried to find an intermediate inequality, but I can't figure out which inequality I should start from.

Something that seemed to be useful was taking P(n) and multiplying it by $(1+\frac{1}{(n+1)^3})$, therefore I have come to this

$(1+ \frac{1}{1^3})(1+\frac{1}{2^3})...(1+\frac{1}{n^3})<3 | \times(1+\frac{1}{(n+1)^3})$

$(1+ \frac{1}{1^3})(1+\frac{1}{2^3})...(1+\frac{1}{n^3})(1+\frac{1}{(n+1)^3})<3(1+\frac{1}{(n+1)^3})$

but, as anyone could imagine, I came to contradiction because I've tried to prove that $3(1+\frac{1}{(n+1)^3})<3$ which is false.

Any help it would be useful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving $\left(1+\dfrac{1}{1^3}\right)\left(1+\dfrac{1}{2^3}\right)\cdots\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n^3}\right)<3$ for all positive integers $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1008934/proving-left1-dfrac113-right-left1-dfrac123-right-cdots-left1)

Answer (score 0):

Using the fact $1+x\le e^x$ for all real $x,$ we have $$\left(1+ \frac{1}{1^3}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{2^3}\right)\cdots\left(1+\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\le \dfrac{9}{4}\exp\left(\sum_{k=3}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k^3}\right).$$ Now use [the fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry%27s_constant#Classical) that $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{k^3}\lt\dfrac{\pi^2}{7}.$$

Comment: Just curious ... Do you have an English language reference for Euler's proof that was cited in your link?  He was a fairly sharp guy, that Leonard.

Comment: @MarkViola: Indeed he is. This was first proved by Leonhard Euler in a 1772 paper, entitled Exercitationes Analyticae. I was unable to locate a translation of it. But, you can find a (different) derivation of that formula [here.](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.twjm/1500407293)